# Facebook Graph API OAuthException

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to query the Facebook Graph API using this query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/584219068304548/feed?access_token=1822027094779314%7C_cHEek6h0R5nm6UIHz9gjp_f4n0
```

And this gives me the expected result, however i'd like to also get the images with the posts, so I add some parameters like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/584219068304548/posts?access_token=1822027094779314|_cHEek6h0R5nm6UIHz9gjp_f4n0?fields=picture,message,id
```

This gives me this response:

```
"error": {
  "message": "Invalid OAuth access token signature.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 190,
  "fbtrace_id": "ETJ3LqzO6ic"
}
```

However, if I add these parameters in the Graph API explorer, it gives me my expected results.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This acces token is one I don't use. I just created a fresh app on facebook for this

Comment: It's still a valid app access token for an app that you presumably are the admin of - so go reset the app secret now, before anyone uses it to perform actions in your app's and therefor ultimately your name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link is wrong, you have two `?` in it.

The correct link is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/584219068304548/posts?access_token=1822027094779314|_cHEek6h0R5nm6UIHz9gjp_f4n0&fields=picture,message,id
```

Then it will work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use graph api explorer. I gives you suggestions automatically. You don't have to put all of your energy in searching correct links.

[image]